# Javascript не работает в Опере после возврата на страницу кнопкой "back"

Tags: javascript

**Господа специалисты!**

Есть функция f(), которая периодически выводит время в секундах и которая в файле index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
// This is just a sample script. Paste your real code here.
if ('this_is' == /an_example/) {
    of_beautifer();
} else {
    var a = b ? (c % d) : e[f];
}    </script>
</head>
<body onload="f()">
<b id="i"></b><br/>
<a href="p.html">CONTINUE</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Когда перехожу по ссылке на страницу p.html, а затем кнопкой браузера "Назад" возвращаюсь на страницу index.html, то в браузере Опера яваскрипт уже не работает. В других браузерах это всё работает отлично. Мне нужно какое-то решение, которое заставит его работать при всяком поъявлении в окне браузера. Прошу Вашей помощи в решении этой задачи.

Answer (score 3):

Это не баг, это фича (кстати, у меня и в фаере так срабатывает). Браузер кеширует страницу в том состоянии, в котором она находится в данный момент. Таким образом, `onload` не вызывается при переходе назад, так как он (в смысле `onload`) уже произошел и принес свои результаты, которые сохранены в кеше. Однако вы можете помешать этому. Например, установить любой обработчик `onunload`:

```
<body onunload="">
```

Это приведет к тому, что кеш станет невалидным и страница перезагрузится при переходе 
назад. Есть и [другие варианты](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching).

**UPD**. Подумав еще раз, признаю, что вышеприведенное не должно касаться вашего случая. И у меня в Опере ваш пример работает. Может, у вас старая версия? Тогда это ранний баг в Опере.

**UPD 2**. Попробовал в 9.21 - не работает. Видимо, проблема старых версий этого браузера.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!!!!!!!!!!!!
Ваше решение сработало!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onload="javascript: f();">
```

Вот так.

Тогда другой вариант. Подключи библиотеку jQuery и вызывай функцию через

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   f();
});
```

Это событие должно корректно работать во всех браузерах.

Comment: Спасибо, но это не помогло

Comment: Вам тоже спасибо за попытку мне помочь!!!!!!